# Disorted image loaded in I/O suspension mode with libjpeg

Tags: image, loading, jpeg, libjpeg, distortion

After couple of days I had to give up and submit this question. What I am trying to do basically is pretty straight forward - here is the code :

```
switch ( state )
{
case INIT:
        if (jpeg_read_header(&p_jpeg.info, true) == JPEG_SUSPENDED)
        {   
            return SUSPEND;
        }
        if (  p_jpeg.info.jpeg_color_space == JCS_CMYK  
           || p_jpeg.info.jpeg_color_space == JCS_YCCK ) return UNSUPPORTED;

        p_jpeg.info.out_color_space = JCS_RGB;
        p_jpeg.info.dct_method =  JDCT_FLOAT;
        p_jpeg.info.dither_mode = JDITHER_FS;
        p_jpeg.info.do_fancy_upsampling = TRUE;
        p_jpeg.info.enable_2pass_quant = FALSE;
        p_jpeg.info.do_block_smoothing = TRUE;
        jpeg_calc_output_dimensions(&p_jpeg.info);
        int row_size = p_jpeg.info.output_width * p_jpeg.info.output_components;
        p_jpeg.samples = (*p_jpeg.info.mem->alloc_sarray)((j_common_ptr) &p_jpeg.info,
                          JPOOL_IMAGE,
                          row_size, 1);

        state = START;
case START:
        if (!jpeg_start_decompress(&p_jpeg.info))
        {   
            return SUSPEND;
        }
        state = WORK;
case WORK:
    JSAMPARRAY samples = p_jpeg.samples;

    while (info->output_scanline < info->output_height) {
        if (jpeg_read_scanlines(info, samples, 1) != 1 ) //one scanline only
        {
            return SUSPEND;   // we need more data            
        }
        //copy line to destination
        char* line = (char*)samples[0];
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < info->output_width; ++i)
        {
            (*row).r  = *line++;
            (*row).g  = *line++;
            (*row).b  = *line++;
        }
   } //end while
   state = DONE;
case DONE:
        while (!jpeg_finish_decompress(&p_jpeg.info))
        {
            return SUSPEND;
        }
        return SUCCESS;
} //switch
```

And with all the files I have from various cameras and other sources everything works like a charm - image gets loaded into RGB buffer and voila! However what bothers me really is fact that I encountered certain JPG images that gets loaded badly distorted - what's worse - also example JPGS included with 8d distribution of libjpeg I am using gets distorted - which means I am doing something wrong probably. Could someone point me in the right direction please ? What is wrong with the code above that sometime works but in - let me stress than again in **VERY** few cases it gives me badly distorted image (look at attached example of 
reference image loaded with above code).

Thanks for any helps!

**Original image file from libjpg 8d distribution:**
[image: Original image file from libjpg 8d distribution]

**Image distortion I am getting in this case with the code above**
[image: Image distortion I am getting in this case with the code above]

PS: The code above is essential extract from the real code - which I guess is irrelevant anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok , I finally managed to get it solved. The problem wasn't in image decoding / loading part but in texture generation part which was missing this little line :

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```